# Print all sheets in one print queue except specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to print all sheets in one print queue without sending each sheet as its own print job? I have put this together, but it sends each sheet as its own print job.

```
Sub print_test()
'Prints orders and asks printer
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show 'list of installed printers to pick from
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If (ws.Name) <> "Work Order" Then
            ws.PrintOut
    End If
        End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does having multiple print jobs cause a problem of some kind?

Comment: Not with excel, but if multiple people print at the same time from different pcs it will mix up the papers from the different people on the printer

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

### Print Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub print_test()
    
    Const ExceptionsList As String = "Work Order" ' comma, no spaces
    
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ish As Object: Set ish = ActiveSheet
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
                dict(ws.Name) = Empty
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        wb.Worksheets(dict.Keys).PrintOut
        ish.Select
    End If

End Sub
```